# want to add a mobile_views directory and use i18n shortcuts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mobile, internationalization, lazy-evaluation

I have a Rails 3.0.9 app, and I am using the i18n module for internationalization.  I am adding all my mobile views inside a folder called mobile_views, which I am adding to the view search path for any request in which a mobile user agent is detected.  I want to be able to use the same 'lazy' shortcuts I use in my regular views to access translations, ie t('.title') in app/mobile_views/users/index.html.erb should refer to this title entry in my en.yml file:

```
en:
  users:
    index:
      title: "A title"
```

just like it would if it were in app/views/users/index.html.erb

I want both the files in views and in mobile_views to be able to access the same i18n translations using the same shortcuts.  In other words, I want the two view folders to map to the same shortcuts without having two different trees in the translation file (ie one for views and the other for mobile views)

How do I configure i18n to do this?

Answer (score 0):

turns out that this happens automatically.

Once I use 
prepend_view_path Rails.root + 'app' + 'mobile_views'
to add my mobile_views directory to the view search path, i18n automatically gives files in that folder the same scopes they have if they were in the regular views folder.  So both directories can map to the same translation tree in the en.yml file.